# Jmeter - Common Response assertion for multiple request

Tags: jmeter, response, assertion

I want a common Response assertion for 200 response code which should be applicable for each sampler request.

However it is also required for some sampler requests to overwrite that from sampler level as (response code 204,500).

Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. JMeter Assertions obey [Scoping Rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) so if you put an Assertion on the same level as Samplers - it will be applied to all samplers
2. If you need to override expected response code for a specific sampler I would recommend changing the response code to 200 via [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) like:

   ```
   if (prev.getResponseCode().equals('500')) {
       prev.setResponseCodeOK()
   }
   ```

   this way the above [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) code will change the individual sampler status code from `500` to `200` so "global" assertion will still be successful.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri
You are the all time savior Man!!!
However is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Also i have to check ignore status in Response assertion so it will allow those above cases to pass as well

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve as per the requirement i can't change the response code

Answer (score 1):

In [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) you can add more Pattern To Test, so add 3: 200,204,500

And check the `Or` checkbox that you will allow to assert either one.

- Note:  Field to check is `Response Code`
- Note:  Pattern Matching rule can be `Equals` or `Contains`

Comment: Thank you,
Is there any other way to do this
As we require 200 response code assertion in common and 204 response code assertion for specific 2 requests and 500 response code assertion for other 10+ requests